# How to update element of nested list from forloop - Python

Tags: python, zip, nested-lists

I'd like to update an element in a nested list from output in a loop. However, I can't figure out how to do so without clunky nested for-loops. I suspect use of `zip` will be necessary, but haven't figure out how to work it in.

I have an empty nested list that I want to fill as the loop progresses:

```
empty_list = [[], [], []]
```

I have a separate nested list, with the same number of elements as lists in `empty_list`:

`lst = [[x], [y], [z]]`

I would like to then generate some output from a loop for each element in `lst`. My desired result is:

```
no_longer_empty_list = [[[x], [output_x_1], [output_x_2]], 
[[y], [output_y_1], [output_y_2]], 
[[z], [output_z_1], [output_z_2]]]
```

where `output_x_1` and `output_x_2` are the outputs from the loop when the element being parsed in the loop is `x` (and the same for `y` and `z`)

Here is what I have constructed so far in pseudo-code:

```
for elem in lst:
    if condition holds:
       generate output_1
       append output_1 to appropriate spot in empty_list  
    elif other condition holds:
       generate output_2
       append output_2 to appropriate spot in empty_list
```

Where I am struggling is how to append the outputs to the right list in the `empty_list`.

Apologies if the syntax/explanation is confusing, I've tried to distill it to an understandable format, but will do my best to explain if it is still unclear

Comment: Why do you need `lst` to be nested list in the first place? Could it be [x, y, z] instead? Equivalently, the `no_longer_empty_list` is three times nested, are you sure you cannot have `[[x, output_x_1, output_x_2], [y, ..]]`?

Comment: @tzinie To simplify the problem, I treated the lists in ```lst``` as variables. But ```x``` would instead be something like ```[1, 2, 3]```. So [x, y, z] wouldn't be possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you have 2 functions; `generate_out1()` and `generate_out2()` as well as a list with elements x, y, z, where each element can be a list.

```
result = []
lst = [x, y, z]

for elem in lst:
   temp = [elem]
   temp.append(generate_out1(elem))
   temp.append(generate_out2(elem))
   result.append(temp)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution where you could modify `processFunc` to return your `[output_y_1, output_y_2]`. And I don't think an `empty_list` is needed.

```py
lst = [[1], [3], [5]]

def processFunc(item):
    return [item + 1, item + 2]

def generateList(lst, processFunc):
    return [map(lambda x: [x], x + processFunc(x[0])) for x in lst]

print(generateList(lst, processFunc)) // [[[1], [2], [3]], [[3], [4], [5]], [[5], [6], [7]]]
```